# Div css overflor auto and not used style table

Tags: css, html, overflow

Привет, ребята.
Столкнулся с проблемой, див блок не хочет отображать скрол.
А еще одна проблема - не подключается таблица стилей после добавления элементов.

Hi, guys.
Faced with a problem, block divas do not want to display to scroll.
And another problem - can not connect after adding stylesheet elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/sombik/nuX6B/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML markup, where you have input type button. The last button onclick handler is not closed. It should be:

```
<input type="button" value="delete" onclick="keyPressTest();" />
```

That should solve your issue. Here is a working JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/RumxQ/

Comment: Thank you very much, for one to learn that there is such an interesting thing